# How to load saved model created by (Weka GUI) into my java application and browse the predicted result

Tags: java, weka

My model is done using "FilteredClassifier" algorithm, then SMO as a 
"classifier" parameter. "weka.classifiers.functions.SMO".

I tried to load my model into java using this code but it is not work

```
SupportVector SOM = (SupportVector) SerializationHelper.read(new 
FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\SOM.model"));
```

and this code

```
FilteredClassifier  SOM = (FilteredClassifier ) 
SerializationHelper.read(new 
FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\SOM.model"));
```

both not working

then I want to browse the data used in building this model (actual value and predicted value).

how I can do it?  Once I have created the model, do I need to load the dataset again?

This is the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier cannot be cast to weka.core.pmml.jaxbbindings.SupportVector
>       at weka.api.Model.main(Model.java:28)

---

This is the error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier cannot be cast to weka.core.pmml.jaxbbindings.SupportVector
at weka.api.Model.main(Model.java:28)
```

Answer (score 1):

> weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier cannot be cast to weka.core.pmml.jaxbbindings.SupportVector

pmml and jaxb are XML related classes, you appear to have imported the wrong package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I import the wrong packages